# Delete/repair files with weird permissions/owner/group

Tags: centos, permissions

I have the following files (output of `ls -l`):

```
?rw-------  6144 1684128777 2049835008 50331648 Jan  1  1970 image1.jpg
br-xrwSrw- 25120 1987343475 1936028517 110, 110 May 30  2032 image2.jpg
?--------- 25966  774963978 1954164340      187 Apr  8  1996 image3.jpg
br--r-xrwT  9776  892169583  859126070  80,  76 May 19  1999 image4.jpg
c--xr-xrw- 25967 1852137846 1931502624  77,  32 Nov 15  2031 image5.jpg
```

A normal file in the same directory looks like:

```
-rw-r--r--     1 apache     apache       198849 Jan 29 21:45 image6.jpg
```

I already tried to remove those weird files with `rm -f` but I got the error:

```
rm: cannot remove `image1.jpg': Operation not permitted
```

When I try to check the flags/remove immutable flag with `lsattr` and `chattr` then I get the following errors:

```
lsattr: Operation not supported While reading flags on image1.jpg
chattr: Operation not supported while reading flags on image1.jpg
```

**Questions**

1. What is going on here? These files seem corrupt?
2. How can I remove/fix these files?

Comment: yes. looks like corruption. Do you share the disk with another os or device?

Comment: Check permissions of the parent directory and if needed add `x` to it.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like file corruption. I would try running `fsck` on the system to see if it can recover the files/fix the filesystem corruption.

#### Example 1: Using the shutdown command

```
[root]# shutdown -rF now
```

#### Example 2: Force fsck on boot using `/forcefsck` file

When you create a `/forcefsck` file you will force the Linux system to perform a full file system check.

Login as the root (if not already):

```
$ su -
```

`touch` a file called `forcefsck`:

```
[root]# touch /forcefsck
```

Now reboot the system:

```
[root]# reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say by looking at the output, it is a bit strange.  I believe you have a filesystem corruption or even a failure of the disk.  You never did say if you looked into your log files and found anything bad.  I'll assume that the disk containing these files are directly connected to your system.

First attempt to take a backup of the failed disk (if you can).  Of course, it is better if you have been taking backups all along.

You can attempt to salvage by attempting to do a FULL fsck on the disk partition.  You may lose some files and directories but hopefully the damage is not significant.

Then try to use the disk.  If things are ok, GREAT.  You can try to remove/delete/modify the problem files (if they are still present).   If not, time to restore from a good backup set.